# How to process lines from two different files in parallel

Tags: python, for-loop

I can insert successfully the TZ.txt file contents (one line at a time) into the url line where %s is, that works perfectly.

I have json formatted data living in TZContents.txt and I need to insert that data into payload = '{}' brackets in the same manner in which the TZ.txt file contents is being inserted. It is not doing that currently at the moment and I feel this isnt set up right. Any suggestions?

I am not concerned about stripping lines in the content file like I am with the TZ.txt file.

Essentially, the code worked fine until I tried to add a payload parameter to insert the payload I have in another file but so far it has not been successful. If you need more information, please let me know. Thank you for your help.

```
import requests, meraki, os, json

with open('TZ.txt') as file, open ('TZContents.txt') as file2:
    array = file.readlines()
    array1 = file2.readlines()
    for line in array:
         for line2 in array1:
             line = line.rstrip("\n")
             url = 'https://dashboard.meraki.com/api/v0/networks/%s' %line
             payload = "{%s}" %line2
             headers = {'X-Cisco-Meraki-API-Key': 'API KEY','Content-Type': 'application/json'}
             response = requests.request('PUT', url, headers = headers, data = payload, allow_redirects=True, timeout = 10)
             print(response.text)
```

Comment: Do you want to go through every line in `array1` for a given line in `array`? Or do you want to go through the two files line by line together? Also, what do you mean by "It is not doing that currently at the moment?" What is happening, and what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: I need to go through each line in each file, which should match up together. For instance. In array it should consist of network ID's and in array 2, contains the parameters for that network in array. Does that make sense. I need them to run at the same time so the information matches up directly line for line in each file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use zip like so:

```
import requests

with open('TZ.txt') as file:
    tz_lines = file.readlines()

with open ('TZContents.txt') as file2:
    tz_contents = file2.readlines()

for name, contents in zip(tz_lines, tz_contents):
    url = 'https://dashboard.meraki.com/api/v0/networks/%s' % name.rstrip("\n")
    headers = {'X-Cisco-Meraki-API-Key': 'API KEY','Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    response = requests.request('PUT', url, headers=headers, data='{%s}' % contents, allow_redirects=True, timeout = 10)
    print(response.text)
```

This is also awfully error prone. If possible, it would be better to generate source data in a manner that doesn't rely on things lining up perfectly. To catch possible errors, you can try this:

```
if len(tz_lines) != len(tz_contents):
    raise RuntimeError("Files are not the same length!")
```

But ideally you'd just keep all the data together in the first place. Saving everything as JSON would be ideal:

```
[
  {"name": "the name string", "payload": {"your": "payload"}},
  "more rows"
]
```

Then you can use `json.load(file)` within those `with` blocks. And requests has good support for JSON, so you can probably pass the decoded JSON directly in just as you did the file contents.

Answer (score 1):

You're actually pretty close, and you clearly have a nose for code that could be improved: well done! Once you have the two files, you need to arrange to process a line from each file in parallel.

One way to do it would be:

```
with open('TZ.txt') as file, open ('TZContents.txt') as file2:
    for line in file1:
        line2 = file2.next()
        ...
```

If the files are small enough to read into memory like you do then you might also consider the `zip` built-in function.

```
>>> list(zip(['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2, 3]))
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
```

So you could instead code it as:

```
with open('TZ.txt') as file, open ('TZContents.txt') as file2:
    for line, line2 in zip(file1, file2):
        ...
```

I hope we can agree that this is pretty readable and seems to make the code's intent clear.

Comment: On average each file contains about 4000+ lines. Would that work?

Comment: In this code, the files are consumed incrementally, so this will work for arbitrarily large files. (Assuming you're using python 3.x, that is. On python 2, use izip from itertools.)